# Finding nth row giving me Duplicates

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot, max

I can query these separately but am trying to combine results into one query.

First query - Income value for most max date

```
SELECT * 
FROM CODES     
INNER JOIN OPS ON CODES.ID = OPS.ID
    AND OPS = 'A'
    AND OPS.DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM OPS WHERE OPS.ID = COLL.ID)
```

OPS TABLE

| ID | DATE 1 | Income 1st year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-01-01 | 5000 |
| 1 | 2015-05-15 | 525 |
| 1 | 2018-01-01 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2018-01-01 | 60000 |
| 2 | 2019-05-15 | 525 |

RESULTS Code/Id is unique and Income is the most recent date

| ID | DATE | Income 1st year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-01-01 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2019-05-15 | 525 |

2nd most recent date income value

```
WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT   
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CODES.ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS ROWNUM,
        OPS.INCOME     
    FROM CODES    
    INNER JOIN OPS ON CODES.ID = OPS.ID AND OPS = 'A'
) 
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE ROWNUM = 2
```

| ID | DATE 2 | Income 2nd year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-01-01 | 5000 |
| 2 | 2018-01-01 | 60000 |

My main question is how to combine these to look like:

| ID | DATE 2 | Income 2nd year | DATE 1 | Income 1st year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-01-01 | 5000 | 2018-01-01 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2018-01-01 | 60000 | 2019-05-15 | 525 |

What I would like the query to look like

```
SELECT 
    date1,
    1st year income,
    date2,
    2nd year income    
FROM CODES 
LEFT JOIN OPS ON CODES.ID = OPS.ID
    AND OPS = 'A'
    AND OPS.DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM OPS WHERE OPS.ID = COLL.ID)    
LEFT JOIN OPS as OPS2 ON CODES.ID = OPS2.ID
    AND OPS2 = 'A'
    AND OPS2.DATE = (SOME FILTER HERE TO GET 2ND ROW WITHOUT CREATING DUPLICATES)
```

This is a small part in a much larger query. I have tried checking the forum but can't seem to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the row-numbering solution, modify to return both first and second rows, then pivot those back out.

```sql
WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT   
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CODES.ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS ROWNUM,
        DATE,
        ID,
        OPS.INCOME     
    FROM CODES    
    INNER JOIN OPS ON CODES.ID = OPS.ID AND OPS = 'A'
) 
SELECT ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 1 THEN DATE END) DATE1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 1 THEN INCOME END) INCOME1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 2 THEN DATE END) DATE2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 2 THEN INCOME END) INCOME2,
FROM T1
WHERE ROWNUM <= 2
GROUP BY ID
```